# Best way to get list of state-level places (google places api)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm currently working a project with the requirement to get a list of state-level places. I've tried the following two APIs but none of them can 100% meet the requirement:

- Google Autocomplete API. In order to get rid off the detailed street-level places I passed `types: ["(regions)"]` which is OK from business' point of view (even though only state-level would be perfect, but city-level is still OK). However when user search for `Washington, USA` the API only returns 5 cities named Washington, and user have to search for `WA, USA` instead.
- Google Places API. This API can successfully handle the `Washington` case above. However I couldn't find a way to restrict the API to get rid off the street-level places, unless I filter the returned places by the `types` attribute.

Does anyone know what is the best API to use for this scenario?

Comment: What is a "state-level" place?  Are you looking for States/Provinces for all countries?

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for reply. What I want is when searching for `Washington, USA`, the API returns the Washington state, not those cities named Washington but in other states. At the moment the only workaround I have is to keep the Google Places API's results which have `administrative_area_level_1` type.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a [Text Search request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) with the search string as `Washington, USA` I get only 1 result which seems to be the WA state.

**Request** (use your own API key): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Washington%2C%20USA&language=en&key=YOUR_API_KEY

**Result**:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Washington, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.7510741,
               "lng" : -120.7401385
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.0024442,
                  "lng" : -116.91558
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 45.543541,
                  "lng" : -124.8489739
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png",
         "name" : "Washington",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2124,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101488181553592859672\"\u003eArko Bhattacharjee\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwLa-P4aH5Uh3rD2CKaZmwb8HyNPWZ1WZUnw_y4iaUouh4B6BKOwAo52kkiBNSfn3MJmkW6Ju50H_e7zhxs5m5oBJva-dywtTv2cF_OgX6COeUfnre_SVmXw1qA4Fof924hSOvutwFnjsO6MJ1R71ozhBfieWrtvN9dSwVbgQbvMu-3y",
               "width" : 1440
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-bDD5__lhVQRuvNfbGh4QpQ",
         "reference" : "ChIJ-bDD5__lhVQRuvNfbGh4QpQ",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Double check this by doing a [Place Details request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) with the returned place id `ChIJ-bDD5__lhVQRuvNfbGh4QpQ`:

**Request** (use your own API key): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJ-bDD5__lhVQRuvNfbGh4QpQ&language=en&key=YOUR_API_KEY

**Result**:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Washington",
            "short_name" : "WA",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United States",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eWashington\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUSA\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "Washington, USA",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 47.7510741,
            "lng" : -120.7401386
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 49.00256875707851,
               "lng" : -116.9155800245149
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 45.54354101516995,
               "lng" : -124.8489739457119
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png",
      "name" : "Washington",
      "photos" : [],
      "place_id" : "ChIJ-bDD5__lhVQRuvNfbGh4QpQ",
      "reference" : "ChIJ-bDD5__lhVQRuvNfbGh4QpQ",
      "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=Washington,+USA&ftid=0x5485e5ffe7c3b0f9:0x944278686c5ff3ba",
      "utc_offset" : -480,
      "website" : "http://www.access.wa.gov/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```